# Выдаёт ошибки в Git

Tags: git, github

Я начал знакомство с Git. Я создаю репозиторий для отслеживания изменений в своём проекте. следующим образом.

```
 git init 
 git config --global user.name "Your Name" (вписал, что надо)
 git config --global user.email you@example.com
```

Дальше создал файл  .gitignore, отобразил и зафиксировал все изменения.
Потом перешёл к созданию коммита для отправки.

```
git commit -m "My first commit ever"
```

Дальше связал локальный репозиторий с гитхабовским

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/MK/my-first-app.git
```

Но, когда я хочу отправить локальный коммит в репозиторий на гитхаб

```
git push origin master
```

Выдаёт это:

```
Fatal: HttpRequestException encountered.
Username for 'https://github.com': MK
Password for 'https://MK@github.com':
To https://github.com/Mk/my-first-app.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Mk/my-first-app.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Что делать и как быть я не знаю, прошу помочь.

Comment: Судя по всему, созданный на гитхабе репозиторий - не пустой. PS: Ни разу не создавал репозиторий, который потом куда-то заливал, через git init. Впрочем, гитхабом тоже не пользовался.

Comment: делали перед коммитом git add .?

Comment: Почему же вы не читаете сообщение? Там приведен один из вариантов решения проблемы.

Comment: @Qwertiy да, репозиторий не пустой, я там редми добавил, попробую переделать, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Если репозиторий на Github свежесозданный, и никем кроме вас не использвался - то скорее всего при создании репозитория вы нажали что-то вроде Initialize with readme прямо в интерфейсе гитхаба. Это добавило в ваш репозиторий на гитхабе стандартный коммит, которого локально у вас нет.

Проверьте историю коммитов на гитхабе, если там один шаблонный коммит - просто перепишите его принудительным пушем:

```
git push -f origin master
```

Если там есть нешаблонные коммиты - выясняйте, откуда они там взялись :)

Comment: не стоит давать новичкам таких советов :) иначе у них этот ключик `-f` отложится в буйной головушке и таких дел потом натворит...

Comment: @КапитанФлинт причем тут головушка? Человек пытается научится с git работать, это включает в себя разбирательства с force push и всякими rebase в том числе, а не просто push/pull. Лучше раньше узнать, что делает force push, чем позже :)

Answer (score 1):

делай `git pull origin master` прежде чем делать `git push...`. всегда делай сначала `pull`, и только потом `push`

Comment: `git pull --rebase ...` уж несколько лучше.

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас уже есть удаленный репозиторий, то вместо пары `git init`, `git remote add` лучше делать `git clone`.

А в сложившейся ситуации у вас два варианта:

1. Выполнить слияние (о чем написано в тексте сообщения об ошибке)
2. Удалить историю в одном из репозиториев